# Get wrong PATH_INFO after rewriting in lighttpd

Tags: python, lighttpd, pathinfo

In my `lighttpd` config file, I have a rewrite rule like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "sub.example.com" {
  url.rewrite = (
     "^/(.*)" => "/sub/$1"
  )
}
```

So when a user visits `http://sub.example.com`, she's actually visiting `http://example.com/sub`.

The problem is that the `PATH_INFO` seems wrong,

```
   URL: http://sub.example.com/extra
   PATH_INFO:
     expected: /extra
     what I get: /sub/extra
```

Now whenever I call `request.get_path()`, it returns something like    `http://sub.example.com/sub/extra`, which is not what I want.

Of course, I can just override the `get_path` method of the `request` class, but I wonder if there is a simpler way like changing the lighttpd config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want pre-rewritten URI try `REQUEST_URI`.  Generally if you have rewrite rules it is the rewritten path you actually want otherwise there is no purpose to the rewriting.

Comment: Could you please refer me to some introduction about request variables like PATH_INFO and REQUEST_URI?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php has many, in PHP you can call `phpinfo()` to see the full list, albeit no description.

Comment: Thanks, Steve-o. I have another question: Can I conclude that REQUEST_URI == SCRIPT_NAME + PATH_INFO ?